# Skip argument is being ignored in useQuery hook from @apollo/react-hooks

Tags: reactjs, apollo, react-apollo, apollo-client, react-apollo-hooks

#### The issue:

Hello, so I've been using apollo-client for a while on my ReactJS application. I've just noticed that sometimes when I use the `useQuery` hook, the execution completely ignores the `skip` argument, and just proceed with the `onCompleted` (albeit without any data). Interestingly enough, it also does not make an API request to my endpoint either. However, if I just set `skip` to false, then everything works properly (as expected).

Also, this doesn't happen every time I use `useQuery` with `skip`, it seems working on some and not others.

Why is apollo ignoring the `skip` argument and just executing `onCompleted` immediately with null data? Is there a fix (other than `useLazyQuery`)?

#### Code example:

```
const userQuery = useQuery(GET_USER, {
    variables: {
      value: userId,
    },
    skip: true,
    onCompleted: props => {
      console.log(`props => `, props)
      const {
        user: { type, role, firstName, lastName, permissions },
      } = props;

      setValue('firstName', firstName);
      setValue('lastName', lastName);
      setValue(
        'type',
        userTypes.find(({ value }) => value === type),
      );
      setValue(
        'role',
        userRoles.find(({ value }) => value === role),
      );
    },
  });
```

Additional notes:

• The output of logging the props from the onCompleted function is `props =>  undefined`.

• I added `skip: true` just to demonstrate the fact that it actually isn't working.

• If I log `userQuery` itself, then immediately on the first log, `userQuery.called` is equal to true (but like I said previously, no API call actually had been executed)

#### Dependencies

```
"@apollo/react-hooks": "^3.1.5",
"apollo-cache-inmemory": "^1.6.3",
"apollo-client": "^2.6.10",
"apollo-datasource-rest": "^0.6.6",
"apollo-link": "^1.2.13",
"apollo-link-context": "^1.0.19",
"apollo-link-error": "^1.1.12",
"apollo-link-rest": "^0.7.3",
"apollo-link-retry": "^2.2.15",
"apollo-link-token-refresh": "^0.2.7",
"apollo-upload-client": "^11.0.0",
"react": "16.10.2",
"react-apollo": "^3.1.3",
```

#### Note:

`useLazyQuery` seems to be working properly, so as a workaround for this in the meantime you can use that in combination with `useEffect` to achieve similar results.

Comment: We also encountered this issue, and others too: https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-client/issues/6190

Answer (score 3):

Apollo Client has issues. The bug in skip is an annoying one. You can abandon GraphQL, or work around them. I recommend abandoning it, but if you can't here is a work around. This module will work similar to useQuery and have skip working. It is incomplete to the full spec, but should get you started.

```
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { QueryHookOptions, useApolloClient } from '@apollo/react-hooks';
import { ApolloQueryResult, NetworkStatus, QueryOptions, ApolloError } from 'apollo-client';

interface DocumentNode {
    loc: {
        source: {
            body: string;
        };
    };
}

interface QueryResult<T> extends ApolloQueryResult<T> {
    error?: Error | ApolloError;
    refetch?: () => void;
}

/**
 * Method: useQuery
 * Description: enable skip on useQuery. There is a bug that currently ignores it. The bug is confirmed in the 3.2 release as well.
 * Note: https://github.com/apollographql/react-apollo/issues/3492
 */
export function useQuery<T>(
    query: DocumentNode,
    options?: QueryHookOptions
): QueryResult<T | null> {
    // Note: using useApolloClient because useLazyQuery fires on initialization. If we are skipping, we don't even want the first fire.
    const apolloClient = useApolloClient();
    const [result, setQueryResult] = useState<QueryResult<T | null>>({
    // Note: initial state
        data: null,
        loading: false,
        stale: false,
        networkStatus: NetworkStatus.ready
    });

    const setResult = (res: QueryResult<T | null>) => {
    // Note: GraphQL and Apollo can't decide if they want to return errors, or error in the type contract. I want to be sure the contract is stable. If there are errors, there will be error.
    if (res.errors?.length && !res.error) {
        [res.error] = res.errors;
    }
    // Note: Functions should always exist even if the query is not complete.
    if (!res.refetch) {
        res.refetch = () => {
            if (!result.loading) {
                execQuery();
            }
        };
      }
      setQueryResult(res);
  };

  const execQuery = async () => {
      // Note: loading state. Not spreading "...result" to allow errors to be reset.
      setResult({
          data: options?.fetchPolicy === 'no-cache' ? null : result.data,
          loading: true,
          networkStatus: NetworkStatus.loading,
          stale: true
      });
      try {
          const queryOptions = ({
              ...options,
              query
          } as unknown) as QueryOptions;
          
          await apolloClient
              .query(queryOptions)
              .then(result => {
                  setResult(result);
                  if(options?.onCompleted) options.onCompleted(result.data);
              })
              .catch(err => {
                  setResult(err);
                  if(options?.onError) options.onError(err);
              });
          
      } catch (err) {
          // Note: fail state
          setResult({
              ...result,
              loading: false,
              errors: [err],
              error: err,
              stale: true,
              networkStatus: NetworkStatus.error
          });
      }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
      // Note: Skip Functionality
      if (!result.loading && options?.skip !== true) {
           execQuery();
      }
  // Note only listen too explicit variables. If you listen to whole objects they are always different and will cause endless loops.
  }, [options?.skip, query.loc.source.body]);

  return result;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use `enabled: false` - that worked for me.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: `enabled: false` is for [react-query](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-query). Not Apollo!

Comment: The enabled argument can be used for Apollo